# Cannot set Boolean value through reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am not able to set a `Boolean` value to a field using Java reflection.
The field data type is `java.lang.Boolean`. however, I am able to set the value if the data type is primitive type i.e `boolean`.

Here is a simple VO with `Boolean` type and primitive type:

```
public class TestVO {
    private Boolean bigBoolean;
    private boolean smallBoolean;
}
```

Here is my java reflection code:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[])
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        TestVO testVO1 = new TestVO();

        Class testVO = testVO1.getClass();
        Field smallBooleanField = TestVO.class.getDeclaredField("smallBoolean");
        Field bigBooleanField = TestVO.class.getDeclaredField("bigBoolean");

        String name1 = smallBooleanField.getName();
        System.out.println("SmallBoolean Fieldname is: " + name1);

        smallBooleanField.setAccessible(true);

        // get the value of this private field
        Boolean fieldValue = (Boolean) smallBooleanField.get(testVO1);
        System.out.println("fieldValue = " + fieldValue);

        smallBooleanField.setAccessible(true);
        smallBooleanField.setBoolean(testVO1, true);

        // get the value of this private field
        fieldValue = (Boolean) smallBooleanField.get(testVO1);
        System.out.println("fieldValue = " + fieldValue);

        name1 = bigBooleanField.getName();
        System.out.println("bigBooleanField Fieldname is: " + name1);

        bigBooleanField.setAccessible(true);

        // get the value of this private field
        fieldValue = (Boolean) bigBooleanField.get(testVO1);
        System.out.println("fieldValue = " + fieldValue);

        bigBooleanField.setAccessible(true);
        bigBooleanField.setBoolean(testVO1, new Boolean(true));

        // get the value of this private field
        fieldValue = (Boolean) bigBooleanField.get(testVO1);
        System.out.println("fieldValue = " + fieldValue);

    }
}
```

Output is:

```
SmallBoolean Fieldname is: smallBoolean
fieldValue = false
fieldValue = true
bigBooleanField Fieldname is: bigBoolean
fieldValue = null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Boolean field TestVO.bigBoolean to (boolean)true
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.setBoolean(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.setBoolean(Field.java:795)
    at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:44)
```

---

I tried to set the `bigBoolean` value with `new Boolean(true)`, `Boolean.TRUE`, `true` etc. nothing works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTrouble.html), `bigBoolean.setBoolean()` is invoked to set a field that is of the reference type Boolean with a value of primitive type. In the non-reflection equivalent `Boolean val = true`, the compiler would convert (or box) the primitive type 'true ' to a reference type as `new Boolean(True)` so that its type checking will accept the statement.

**When using reflection, type checking only occurs at runtime so there is no opportunity to box the value. This forces to throw `IllegalArgumentException` due to Inconvertible Types**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and for the solution. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line and it should work for you:

```
bigBooleanField.set(testVO1, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and reason is not reflection reason is getter method type. If you notice for boolean/Boolean your IDE create a getter method as isVariableName() instead of getVariableName(). If you change your method name to get type it will work fine.